# How to send data between two remote machines using socket programming?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, port, firewall

I'm trying to send data from one remote computer (Ubuntu) to my home computer (High Sierra). I've read [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044013/send-data-to-remote-server-using-sockets) [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49364513/sending-data-from-server-to-client-socket-programming) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40765102/connecting-two-machines-using-socket) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240078/connecting-to-a-private-ip) here at SO, but they don't seem to give a solution to my problem. I'm connected to the remote computer with ssh, and created and successfully compiled the following programs on both computers.

**client.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string address = argv[1];
    int port = 38473;
    int success;

    // http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html
    int server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (server_socket == -1)
        return errno;

    sockaddr_in socket_address{};
    socket_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socket_address.sin_port = htons(port);  // htons - Host to Network Short. Flip endianness to match machine.
    success = inet_pton(AF_INET, address.c_str(), &socket_address.sin_addr);  // Pointer (to String) to Number.
    if (success <= 0)
        return errno;

    success = connect(server_socket, (sockaddr*)&socket_address, sizeof(socket_address));
    if (success == -1)
        return errno;

    std::cout << "Connected" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        write(server_socket, "Hello!\n", 7);
}
```

**server.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <cstring>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string address = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 38473;
    int success;

    // http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html
    int listen_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listen_socket == -1)
        return errno;

    sockaddr_in socket_address{};
    socket_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socket_address.sin_port = htons(port);  // htons - Host to Network Short. Flip endianness to match machine.
    success = inet_pton(AF_INET, address.c_str(), &socket_address.sin_addr);  // Pointer (to String) to Number.
    if (success <= 0)
        return errno;

    // http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html
    success = bind(listen_socket, (sockaddr*)&socket_address, sizeof(socket_address));
    if (success == -1)
        return errno;

    // http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html
    success = listen(listen_socket, 10);
    if (success == -1)
        return errno;

    sockaddr_in client_address;
    socklen_t   client_address_size = sizeof(client_address);
    int client_socket = accept(listen_socket, (sockaddr*)&client_address, &client_address_size);
    if (client_socket == -1)
        return errno;

    close(listen_socket);

    size_t buffer_size = 4096;
    char buffer[buffer_size];
    ssize_t bytes_received;

    std::cout << "Connected" << std::endl;
    while (true)
    {
        memset(buffer, 0, buffer_size);
        // http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html

        if ((bytes_received = read(client_socket, buffer, buffer_size)) <= 0)
            return 0;
        std::cout << "Message: " << buffer << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When running both programs on the same machine (where the client executable takes 127.0.0.1 as argument in the command line), it works perfectly and the data is sent. When trying to run my local computer as a server and running client.cpp from the remote, I get the error code 111 (connection refused).

After reading various tutorials/blogs/posts, this seems to be that:

1. The port currently isn't listening.
2. The firewall is preventing the connection.

I've tried solving this by doing the following.

### The port currently isn't listening.

As the remote machine is trying to connect to my public IP-address, I have to forward a port to my local machine. I logged in to my router and added an entry to forward the port 38473 to my private IP-address. This port was randomly chosen as [iana](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=unassigned) had marked it unassigned, and it was quite large. Since I can send data when running both programs on one machine, I assume the port isn't the issue.

[image: Port forwarding table]

### The firewall is preventing the connection.

I've made sure to disable my firewall the local machine (In System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Firewall) and made an entry in my router allowing messages from the remote machine (using its public IP-address) via port 38473.

[image: Firewall configurations]

I still don't seem to be able to connect. I ran [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and could see that the remote did send a SYN request, but got a [RST, ACK] in return. The [RST flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_reset_attack) seems to be a way for the firewall to terminate a connection, but I don't see why it would do that considering my previous configurations above.

[image: Wireshark output]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your server is only listening to localhost (127.0.0.1).  It needs to listen to all IPs or the IP (the *local* IP) the traffic will come in on, such as 192.168.1.2 (or whatever).

Comment: PS--Typically "connection refused" indicates not listening vs a timeout which will typically indicate a firewall or router just dropped the traffic (which is how they typically behave)

Comment: @zzxyz Oh okay, as many have written that "Connection refused" meant that the port wasn't listening, I assumed the address was irrelevant and it always listened to all incoming addresses. But it makes sense to not do that :P I tried now to change the IP-address to 0.0.0.0 and it worked! Thank you! ^^

Comment: Easy mistake to make given most of the example code out there....Sorry for your suffering :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your server code to listen to the IP of the ethernet card you are interested in on the computer, OR:

```
   serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
```